# Connecting to MySQL from Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm trying to connect to a local MySQL instance using the methodology provided in the documentation. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
Sub connectToDB()
    Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

    conn.connectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=myDB;" & _
        "USER=myUser;" & _
        "PASSWORD=myPassword;" & _
        "OPTION=3;"

    conn.Open
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from object"
    Set recset = cmd.Execute()
    recset.MoveFirst
    MsgBox recset.Fields(1).Value

    conn.Close

End Sub
```

The driver is installed:

[image: MySQL ODBC Admin]

...and I've verified connectivity through the ODBC Administrator Test button:

[image: MySQL ODBC Test]

However, when I run this in VBA, I get a message saying "Data source name not found and no default driver specified":

[image: MySQL ODBC VBA]

I have plenty of experience using ADO to connect to SQL Server in the same way, but I haven't done it in a while, so feel free to call me a noob if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Check whether Excel is running in 32-bit mode (check Task Manager). If you Excel exe is 32 bit then you should set-up the ODBC source in 32-bit mode. It should be here: `%WINDIR%\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Good call. It's 32-bit, so I installed the 32-bit driver and good to go. Thanks a lot.